# How to listen for Pub/Sub messages in an ASP.NET Core app continuously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to implement an ASP.NET Core API, which is not responding to HTTP requests, but upon startup starts listening to Google Cloud Pub/Sub messages, and it keeps listening indefinitely throughout its lifetime.

What is the preferred way to implement this with the official Pub/Sub SDK?

I can think of two ways:

**Approach 1**: Just use a `SimpleSubscriber`, and in the `Startup.Configure` start listening to messages:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var simpleSubscriber = await SimpleSubscriber.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);
    var receivedMessages = new List<PubsubMessage>();

    simpleSubscriber.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        // Process the message here.

        return Task.FromResult(SimpleSubscriber.Reply.Ack);
    });

    ...
}
```

**Approach 2**: Use a library specifically created to periodically run a job, for example Quartz, Hangfire or FluentScheduler, and every time the job is triggered, pull the new messages with a `SubscriberClient`.

Which one is the preferred approach? The first one seems simpler, but I'm not sure if it's really reliable.

Comment: @Flater this is an ASP.NET Core application running in Kubernetes. I would like the app to have both some REST endpoints, **and** keep listening to some Pub/Sub messages. (I know I could separate these two things into two components, but if it's possible, I'd like to keep it as one for convenience.)

Comment: I'd start with the simplest approach and then if needed move to a library. In you sample I'd only add code for keeping `simpleSubscriber` somewhere in static field to protect the object from GC

Comment: As far as I'm *aware*, the first approach should be fine - but I'm checking with a colleague who knows more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach is definitely how this is intended to be used.

However, see the docs for `StartAsync`:

> Starts receiving messages. The returned `Task` completes when either
> `StopAsync(CancellationToken)` is called or **if an unrecoverable
> fault occurs**. This method **cannot be called more than once** per
> `SubscriberClient` instance.

So you do need to handle unexpected `StartAsync` shutdown on unrecoverable error. The simplest thing to do would be be use an outer loop, although given these errors are considered unrecoverable it is likely something about the call needs to be changed before it can succeed.

The code might look like this:

```
while (true)
{
    // Each SubscriberClientinstance must only be used once.
    var subscriberClient = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);
    try
    {
        await subscriberClient.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            // Process the message here.
            return Task.FromResult(SimpleSubscriber.Reply.Ack);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Handle the unrecoverable error somehow...
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work as expected, please [let us know](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/new).

**Edit**: `SimpleSubscriber` was renamed to `SubscriberClient` in the library so the answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info! By unrecoverable error, you mean something like stack overflow, or out of memory, so it wouldn't stop due to a transient network failure, or something like that, right? Btw. how is the listening implemented, is the `SimpleSubscriber` polling internally, or does Pub/Sub support something like a WebSocket connection?

Comment: @MarkVincze SimpleSubscriber source code is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SimpleSubscriber.cs so you can see for yourself ;) It uses a long-running streaming RPC call, which is started on line 613.

Comment: @MarkVincze "unrecoverable" means an unrecoverable RPC error. The list of *recoverable* RPC errors is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Extensions.cs#L61 All others are unrecoverable.

Comment: Note that SimpleSubscriber has been renamed to SubscriberClient. New GitHub link: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SubscriberClient.cs

Comment: Hi @Chris : I am trying to use above code but it is not working. listener not working properly in .Net Core. Can you please help me to find working solution.